# ordinary vs multiple regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

This is something confusing me for a while! Hope someone can help me a bit here.
For example my data is like this (n=130):

```
dv = as.numeric(-0.167, 0.960, 1.057, -1.128, 0.613)
iv1 = as.numeric(0,1,1,2,0)
iv2 = as.factor("H","L","H","H","L")
```

now if I run `lm(dv ~ iv1*iv2)`, I assume my data is split into two groups since I have only two levels for iv2 to estimate the interaction term? However, if I run `lm(dv ~ iv1)` or `lm(dv ~ iv2)`, the coefficients and p-values are different than in the first lm.
Can someone explain why is this, or direct me to a reading material? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I changed the title because nothing in this question is pertinent to "multivariate regression" (which concerns the case of a multivariate *dependent* variable).  By searching our site for posts on multiple regression you can find a great many explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're initial model would have been in the form of `lm(dv ~ iv1+iv2)`, thus without interactions, you would have most likely gotten different coefficients. The reason for that is that there is multicollinearity between the predictors.

Let's assume you add 2 predictors that each explains 50% of the variability of your independent data. It is highly unlikely that combining them both would explain 100% of the variability - the reason for that is that part of the variability explained by 1 variable is also explained by the other as they are correlated to each other. In which case the strength of the effect of both variables combined will be weaker than the strength of the effect of the sum of both variables. Therefore each of the coefficients should be adjusted accordingly with respect to the other predictor.

For example, if you want to find out height by shoe size and you found that an increase of 1 size translates into an increase of 1 ft in height. Then you do the same for age, and you find that until the age of 18, an increase of year of age, translates to an increase in 1/2 ft. Since you do know that shoe size increases with age as well, you don't assume that an increase of 1 year and a shoe size of 1 would result in an increase of 1.5 ft, as the effects are never cumulative.

Now as for your question with interactions - that is even simpler. 
The coefficient of your numeric variable that you see assumes a base group (let's assume H). That means that your numeric coefficient iv1 doesn't even show its own independent effect but rather the effect given you're in group H:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.4012     1.2705   0.316    0.805
iv1          -0.4805     0.9841  -0.488    0.711
iv2L          0.2118     1.8844   0.112    0.929
iv1:iv2L      0.8275     2.2005   0.376    0.771
```

(let's disregard p values)
As you see you don't have H written anywhere. That means that the model treats H as the base group. Thus,

the intercept given (base) group H is 0.4.

iv1: Given group H, dv decreases by 0.48 for each step of iv1.

iv2L: group L adds 0.2 to the intercept (thus the intercept of group L is 0.6)

iv1:iv2L : the effect of iv1 given you're in group L.

So as you see, you can't even tell iv1 true sole effect as it is part of one of 2 groups. 
And as I explained before, even if you used iv1+iv2 (no interactions model) you would still see different coefficients due to the multicollinearity.

Hope that helps